# What does the history of this function "createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2" means?

Tags: python, opencv

I only see this description in this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/de/de1/group__video__motion.html#ga2beb2dee7a073809ccec60f145b6b29c), it hasn't a very detailed explanation, so I'd like to know where can I find a more detailed explanation.The official web document says "Length of the history", what "Length of the history" is?

[image]

My code:

```
import os
import time
import cv2

def main():
    img_src_dirpath = r'C:/Users/Shinelon/Desktop/SRC/'
    dir = r'D:/deal_pics/' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '/'
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.makedirs(dir)
    img_dst_dirpath = dir
    history = 60
    varThreshold = 16
    detectShadows = True
    mog2 = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2( history, varThreshold, detectShadows )
    for f in os.listdir( img_src_dirpath ):
        if f.endswith( '.jpg' ):
            img = cv2.imread( img_src_dirpath + f )
            mog2.apply( img )
            bg = mog2.getBackgroundImage()
            cv2.imwrite( img_dst_dirpath + f, bg )
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Does the description of [`getHistory`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/db/d88/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractorKNN.html#adca11897141bae5e5959ace3e6dd3896) help you any further?

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

As @usr2564301 said [getHistory](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/db/d88/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractorKNN.html#adca11897141bae5e5959ace3e6dd3896) gives you good explanation in human language

> Returns the number of last frames that affect the background model.

If you need a mathematical explanation of what it is - I would recommend you to read [An improved adaptive background mixture model for real-time tracking with shadow detection](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.12.3705&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper which this algorithm is based on.
As you can see from sources ([1](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/cudabgsegm/src/mog2.cpp), [2](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/cudabgsegm/src/cuda/mog2.cu)) `history` is used to calculate `learningRate` which is essentially alpha in that paper

[image]